# How to align a GridPane based on position of a single node?

Tags: java, javafx

Say I have a scene. I have a grid pane in it which contains 2 x 2 buttons. I can align this whole grid pane exactly in the center by simply doing `gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);` however I want it the whole grid pane to be positioned on the position of one node.

Here is an illustration:
[image: a busy cat]
The whole grid pane is aligned in the center. What I want is to set the position of `r2 c1` exactly in the center and I want the other three nodes positioned above and besides it respectively. 
I can position a single button but I do not know how to make the whole grid pane positioned based on the position of one node.

Here is the code I wrote for the illustration:

```java
    private BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    private Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1366, 768);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.addRow(0, new Button("r1 c1"), new Button("r1 c2"));
        gridPane.addRow(1, new Button("r2 c1"), new Button("r2 c2"));
        gridPane.setVgap(20);
        gridPane.setHgap(30);
        gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setCenter(gridPane);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

The r2c1 node should exactly be in the middle and the rest of the buttons positioned based on its position. Here is the desired view:
[image: actual representation]
r2c1 starts exactly from the center of the screen and the other nodes are moved corresponding to it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just positioned or should the `GridPane` bounds be treated as the bounds of the child of the grid? Should the `BorderPane` still prevent the right node from being covered by the center node or is the center node covering the right one desired?

Comment: @fabian Just positioned. Just imagine moving the whole GridPane as a whole. The origin should the the position of the r2c1(as from my illustration)

Comment: Centered nodes are not positioned based on their origin. They are positioned in a way that leaves the same amount of space to both sides, i.e. horizontally the positioning is done based on the following equation `xMin = parentWidth - xMax = parentWidth - (xMin + width)`

Comment: @fabian I ain't really sure or am able to understand what you mean. Can you provide a code snippet for the same as the answer referring to my main question?

Comment: Please illustrate what is the desired view. "Just imagine moving the whole GridPane as a whole" suggests that you need to change the `GridPane` parent (in this case `root`) layout.

Comment: What is the purpose of the 3 empty quadrants ? If for other `Pane`s consider using a  2x2 `TilePane` (or `GridPane`) as parent.

Comment: It is just for the purpose of showing the midpoint of both axes. Anyways thanks for the answer! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"moving the whole GridPane as a whole" requires changing the way `GridPane` is laid out with in it's parent (and not the internal layout of the `GridPane` itself). 
There are a few alternatives to achieve it. Manipulating the parent layout is one.
Setting translation to the `GridPane` is another:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FxMain extends Application {

    private static final int VGAP = 20, HGAP = 30;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        Button button1 = new Button("r1 c1");
        gridPane.addRow(1, button1, new Button("r1 c2"));
        gridPane.addRow(2, new Button("r2 c1"), new Button("r2 c2"));
        gridPane.setVgap(VGAP); gridPane.setHgap(HGAP);
        gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        //apply row-height + vgap down translate (row height represented by
        //button height)
        gridPane.translateYProperty().bind(button1.heightProperty().add(VGAP));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 200);
        root.setCenter(gridPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:** after clarifying the desired layout: 
The technique is similar. Enclose the `GridPane` in an `AnchorPane` and apply the desired translation:

```
public class FxMain extends Application {

    private static final int VGAP = 20, HGAP = 30;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane(gridPane); //enclose grid in an AnchorPane
        gridPane.addRow(1, new Button("r1 c1"), new Button("r1 c2"));
        gridPane.addRow(2, new Button("r2 c1"), new Button("r2 c2"));
        gridPane.setVgap(VGAP); gridPane.setHgap(HGAP);

        //apply y translation: (root height/2)  minus grid pane height
        gridPane.translateYProperty().bind(root.heightProperty().divide(2).subtract(gridPane.heightProperty()));
        //apply x translation of root widt / 2
        gridPane.translateXProperty().bind(root.widthProperty().divide(2));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is quite similar to what I am wanting to do but not exactly. I've edited the main question which shows the desired view I want. Thanks.

Comment: I'm still not getting how to make it start at the origin(The center of the screen)

Comment: See my edit. The solution is not meant to be exactly what you need but help you get the idea.